# Symfony4 generate API rest with crud

Tags: json, rest, symfony

With Symfony4 I'm trying to generate a API Rest.

With my existing database and doctrine I generate all the Entity, with make bundle I generate the CRUD controller.

The result is actually in html, I need to manually change the result, for exemple :

```
return $this->render('user/show.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
```

by

```
$data =  $this->get('serializer')->serialize($user, 'json');

$response = new Response($data);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return $response;
```

Did I miss something when I generate the CRUD ? Does it's possible to generate it directly with Json Response ?

Answer (score -1):

If you read the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html it seems that all the available options are:

- `--entity`
- `--route-prefix`
- `--with-write`
- `--format`
- `--overwrite`

I don't see any option to generate your Controller the way you want, so it might be no, you can't generate it directly with Json Response.

Comment: I don't use SensioGeneratorBundle since it's deprecated, I ask this question because may be an other bundle allow me to do that